# Need to write many customer records to a single line in text file

Tags: c#, file, text, stringbuilder, textwriter

I have a client that wants a text file with all the text on a single line.  Like an EDI file has.

I have a datatable with thousands of customers and customer information.  My method loops through the datatable grabs the customer info and writes it to a text file.  Each line in the text file has information for one customer.  There are thousands of customers, which means thousands of lines in the text file.

I don't know how to put all the customers on one single line in the text file.  If anybody has some suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please show your current, relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `WriteLine` to write each customer, you can use [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.write.aspx) (which won't add the new line), and also `Write` some delimiter (space, tab, etc) between each customer.

Answer (score 0):

Say I have some array of strings ( `string[]` ) with all the names, it could really be any collection implementing `IEnumerable<T>` just do;

```
 string OneBigLine = String.Join(MyDelimiter, myStringArray);
 File.WriteAllText(OneBigLine);
```

Or to make it all one line;

```
File.WriteAllText(String.Join(MyDelimiter, myStringArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the file opened, you can append more customers with your `StreamWriter` `Write` method, instead of the classic `WriteLine`.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
{
    foreach (Customer customer in customers)
    {
        sw.Write(customer.Name);
    }    
}
```

If you need to open the file each time, you can use the overload of `StreamWriter` that appends new text instead of overwriting it.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt", true))
{
    sw.Write(customer.Name);  
}
```

You will also need to add a delimiter manually if you need one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers.  However, I went with the following.
The writeline has a default return carriage line feed characters like this.  \r\n

I adjusted the Newline property to a blank string like this sw.NewLine = "";.

sw is my streamwriter.  This does exactly what I wanted.  Instead of adding new rows, it just creates one very long row.

Comment: Thats pretty bad if you ask me. Why wont you use Write instead of WriteLin?